# Using sys.dm_os_sys_info for SQL 2008 R2 and above

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a query to gather memory stats across my multiple SQL editions that are SQL 2008 R2, SQL 2012, SQL 2014, SQL 2016.

Due to the column name changes in sys.dm_os_sys_info I'm trying to get around that, but both of the queries fail with:

**Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'physical_memory_kb'.**

Any ideas?

```
IF (LEFT(cast(serverproperty('productVersion') as varchar(100)),2) = '10')
BEGIN
    select physical_memory_in_bytes/1048576 FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select physical_memory_kb/1024 FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info  
END

select 
    CASE LEFT(cast(serverproperty('productVersion') as varchar(100)),2)
    WHEN 10 Then  physical_memory_in_bytes/1048576
    ELSE  physical_memory_kb/1024
    END
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you've got is compilation error, i.e. parser tries to figure out the columns of existing tables/views and it doesn't consider execution flow (IF)

You can use this code for your purpose:

```
IF (LEFT(cast(serverproperty('productVersion') as varchar(100)),2) = '10')
BEGIN
    exec('select physical_memory_in_bytes/1048576 FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    exec ('select physical_memory_kb/1024 FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info')  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a conditional statement to select from non-existent columns like that, the compiler will still validate all the statements within the select clause.

The first conditional works because it is two distinct select statements.

I would suggest using the first conditional only, if you need additional info then select the physical_memory_in... column into a temp table or table variable and then join that into your main query.